# IcCube Reporting V8 - possible to use Gantt chart?

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart, iccube, iccube-reporting

Using IcCube Reporting V7, I was able to create AmCharts Gantt charts as following :
[image]

Using following mdx behind the scene :

```
with member HDebut as [Measures].[Bloc Début Intervalle], format_string = "hh:mm"
 member HFin as [Measures].[Bloc Fin Intervalle], format_string = "hh:mm"
 member Date as [Measures].[Bloc Début Intervalle], format_string = "dd/mm/yyyy"
select
// Measures
{HDebut, HFin, Date, [Measures].[Bloc Début Intervalle], [Measures].[Bloc Fin Intervalle]} on 0,
// Columns
non empty [Temps utilisation bloc].[Temps utilisation bloc].[TempsIccube] *  [Intervalle_Temps_Minute].[Intervalle_Temps_Minute] on 1,
non empty nonempty ([Salle_Box].[Salle_Box].[Salle], [Modélisation Minutes] ) * nonempty ([Numéro Unique].[Numéro Unique].[NumUnique], [Modélisation Minutes])
    ON 2
FROM 
    [Cube] 
    where {[Date PH].[Libellé Jour Mois Année].[Jour].&[2022-01-01]}
    * {[Temps utilisation bloc].[Temps bloc, visualisation].[Groupe visualisation].[Patient]}
    * {[Salle_Box].[Groupe de Salle].[All-M]}
```

Can I still do it using IcCube Reporting V8 ?  What would be the way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, icCube does not support gantt charts out of the box. However, we agree with you that the gantt chart is a valuable addition to the icCube charting library of v8 (as it was for v7). We are going to add the gantt chart for the next release v8.3.1.

[edit] Actually available in `v8.4.6`.